# Can't display xml file after adding xsl stylesheet

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Everything worked fine, before. Then when I added the style reference to my xml all I get is a blank page in most browsers. ALthough in firefox I get an error that says."XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" and it points to line 16 where my second tr tag. When i view it in the Preview tool in Coda I can see my table headers and the h1, but none of the data shows up. It's a very simple document. It's formatted exactly like the example on w3c [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp). I've tried going though the other solutions on here, but none of them seem to fix my problem. I've also tried various combinations of headers, all with no luck. I really appreciate the help. Thanks

THE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>

<FRIENDLIST>
    <FRIEND>
        <NAME>Speen</NAME>
        <AGE>23</AGE>
        <ADDRESS>430 I Street, SLC UT</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>801-555-8796</PHONE>
        <EMAIL>xxx</EMAIL>
    </FRIEND>

    <FRIEND>
        <NAME>Wafiq</NAME>
        <AGE>25</AGE>
        <ADDRESS>xxx</ADDRESS>
        <PHONE>325-555-4232</PHONE>
        <EMAIL>xxx</EMAIL>
    </FRIEND>
</FRIENDLIST>
```

THE XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>My Friends</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="grey">
                        <th style="text-align:center">Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Age</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Address</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Phone</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Email</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="friendlist/friend">
                    <tr> 
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Age"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Address"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>            
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in firefox.

Data is not showing up as xpath is case sensitive. Change your xsl to use correct xpath selectors.

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="FRIENDLIST/FRIEND">
<tr> 
    <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="AGE"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ADDRESS"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="PHONE"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="EMAIL"/></td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like Google Chrome just doesn't allow the viewing of local xml files. Other browsers work fine.

[Bug Report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58151)